# Time taken to train Resnet on CIFAR-10

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, resnet

I was writing a neural net to train Resnet on **CIFAR-10** dataset.
The paper [Deep Residual Learning For Image Recognition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) mentions training for around 60,000 epochs.

I was wondering - what exactly does an epoch refer to in this case? Is it a single pass through a minibatch of size 128 (which would mean around 150 passes through the entire 50000 image training set?

Also how long is this expected to take to train(assume CPU only, 20-layer or 32-layer ResNet)? With the above definition of an epoch, it seems it would take a very long time...

I was expecting something around 2-3 hours only, which is equivalent to about 10 passes through the 50000 image training set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper never mentions 60000 epochs. An *epoch* is generally taken to mean one pass over the full dataset. 60000 epochs would be insane. They use 64000 *iterations* on CIFAR-10. An iteration involves processing one minibatch, computing and then applying gradients.

You are correct in that this means >150 passes over the dataset (these are the epochs). Modern neural network models often take days or weeks to train. ResNets in particular are troublesome due to their massive size/depth. Note that in the paper they mention training the model on two GPUs which will be much faster than on the CPU.

If you are just training some models "for fun" I would recommend scaling them down significantly. Try 8 layers or so; even this might be too much. If you are doing this for research/production use, get some GPUs.

Comment: I understand. So if I would use a typical nvidia gpu on a laptop how long would you estimate a 20-layer resnet to take?

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't know. [Here's a link](https://medium.com/@andriylazorenko/tensorflow-performance-test-cpu-vs-gpu-79fcd39170c) where a guy gets only ~2x speedup on a laptop, but >10x on a desktop when comparing GPU to CPU.  
However I feel like most laptop GPUs don't have enough RAM to work with such large models -- you would need to use very small batch sizes which generally means more iterations are needed. You would probably want 8+GB per GPU whereas most laptop GPUs I see have maybe 2-4GB.